# edit a TextView in a TableView cell in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, textview, tableview

I'm stuck: I have a TableView populated by .xib cells that I made. Each of these cells contains an editable TextView.
I'm trying to save on my Firebase database the text that the user input in those TextViews. I don't want to implement any button, the text should be saved as soon as the TextView editing end.

I tried to connect the TextView from the .xib file to the UITableViewCell class but it doesn't allow me to connect it as an IBAction but only as outlet or outlet connection.

Please Help me, thanks!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDWRU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved replacing the TextViews with TextFields that could look the same but could be linked to the UITableViewCell.swift as IBAction.
Thus I wrote the code to update the "comments" section of my database inside the IBAction:

```
@IBAction func commentTextFieldToggle(_ sender: UITextField) {
        if commentTextField.text != "" {
            let comment = commentTextField.text
            // I declared the next 7 constants to retreive the exact position of the string "comment" that I want to change
            let date = dateLabel.text!
            let time = timeLabel.text!
            let year = date.suffix(4)
            let day = date.prefix(2)
            let partialMonth = date.prefix(5)
            let month = partialMonth.suffix(2)
            //I use this "chosenDate" constant to retreive the database query that I previously saved using the date in the below format as index:
            let chosenDate = "\(year)-\(month)-\(day) at: \(time)"

            let commentsDB = Database.database().reference().child("BSL Checks")
            commentsDB.child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child(String(chosenDate)).child("Comments").setValue(comment) {
                (error, reference) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                } else {
                    print("User Data saved successfully")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` in your
   `UITableViewCell` class.
2. Connect the `delegate` of the `UITextView` to the cell class.
3. Do whatever you want in the `func textViewDidEndEditing(UITextView)` which you need to implement in your cell class.

Here you can read more: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618603-textviewshouldendediting?changes=_2

Comment: Uhm... I'm trying to follow your steps but I need more help: 

1. - class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate { ...

2. - self.textView.delegate = self

3. - ??